# Mantendo a URL / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

Tenho cerca de 10 dominios em wordpresss, porém gostaria que ao acessar cada domínio ele abra o site em seu próprio dominio.

Ex:
- Ao acessar o dominio01.com.br ele deve abrir o site no dominio01.com.br ao invés de redirecionar para o dominio principal que está definido no wp-config e no DB;

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?
Lembrando que no define do wordpress e o banco eu sempre defino a URL.

Comment: É um multisite? Ou são 10 dominios que carregam o mesmo site?

Comment: 10 domínios parkeados :(

Answer (score 0):

Solução possível, não testada:

no seu `wp-config.php`, coloque:

```
$dominios = array( 'dominio1.com.br', 'dominio2.com.br' );

if ( in_array( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $dominios, true ) {
    define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
    define('WP_SITEURL','http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
}
```

**CUIDADO:** Ao fazer isso você está abrindo a possibilidade que o seu site responda a consultas de qualquer domínio definido no array, desde que elas cheguem ao seu servidor corretamente. Avalie bem os prós e contras.